# unable to get exception from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, c#-4.0

I used on change event to textbox in mvc everything works fine but I am unable to handle exception throw by controller in view.

```
**VIEW:**



 $("#txtToloc").change( function (event) {

        var toloc= $('#txtToloc').val();
                    var mn = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["MODELNUMBER"])%>;
                    var fm = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["lblocation"]) %>;
                    var it = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["lbinvtype"])%>;
                    var whid = "14";
                    debugger;

            $.ajax({
                url: '<%: Url.Action("GetPartialGraph")%>',
                data: { 'Tolocation' :mn, 'Frmlocation' :fm, 'moNo' :it, 'whid' : whid },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                 success: function(result) {
                 alert('yeap');
                  },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  alert(‘loss’);
                }
            });
        });
        });
```

From view i am calling action method in controller.

```
    **CONTROLLER.**



  public ActionResult GetPartialGraph(string Tolocation, string Frmlocation, string moNo, string whid)
            {

                string isvalid = "0";
                if (Frmlocation.ToUpper().Trim() == Tolocation.ToUpper().Trim())
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {                    
                        ut.Setlocation(Tolocation,Frmlocation,moNo,whid);
                    }

                    catch (iDB2Exception ex)
                    {
                       /* in catch depending upon certain condition I want through diff exception */

                           return View(isvalid);  
                     }


 Everything works fine. But I am unable to bring exception back to view. To show proper message to client. From 

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(‘loss’);
            }
```

I am going to call another function and depending upon return I am going to show message to user. Iam unable to return exception from controller to show in view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a view, so the `error` function will never be executed. You could set the status code to 500 and return a JSON result:

```
catch (iDB2Exception ex)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    return Json(new { errorMessage = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then in your error handler simply read this value:

```
error: function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('application/json') > -1) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
        alert(json.errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanqs lot. but inside catch i have 10 condition. all condition and correspondent message are associated with if else condition. i have to store 1 caught exception in string "isvalid " and want to pass it to my view. I am new to mvc. strucked in this

Comment: You could store the error message in a variable and outside of the catch statements return the Json result.

Answer (score 0):

The error function will get executed only when HTTP status code is different from 200. In the code you've posted, you're still returning a valid view - and hence error function wouldn't be executed.

You might be returning a JSON object from the controller. Try setting a 'success' flag in the JSON object, and validate this on your 'success' method:

```
             function(result) {
                 if (result.success)
                     alert('yeap');
              }
```