# Throwing an exception and return a status code AND a message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

I need to throw an exception from my asp.net mvc controller to return to the client.

I can do:

`throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);` to return a status code.

or I can do:

`throw new HttpRequestException("You must fill the name!");` to return a message.

**My question:** is it possible to combine both solutions to provide a status code AND a message?

Somethink like:

`throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Fill the name!");`

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Please note that this is an asp.net MVC website but using the Breeze framework. I need to throw an exception when my validation failed (so before saving my changes server side).

```
public class TPBContextProvider : EFContextProvider<BreezeContext>
{

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)  
    {
        ...
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
```

Comment: I don't think your DAL should throw HTTP errors. Consider using your own exception class, like `ContextException`, which you may give a specific error code which you catch in your action method, where you in turn can translate that code into an HTTP status code and a message.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried returning an [`HttpStatusCodeResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) instead of throwing up:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Fill the name!")
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, this is effectively an asp.net mvc website but using the breeze framework. I need to throw an error but not from an ActionResult, I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: @bronzato : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17653933/2015869

Answer (score 2):

I think that this will work

```
  var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
  responseMsg.Content = new StringContent("Custom error message");
  throw new HttpResponseException(responseMsg);
```